# Ajax POST XMLHttpRequest() can't send parameters with & characther

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

In my code i have to send an ajax POST call like this:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "bac="+pa+"&seid="+psid+"&wh="+height;
http.open("POST", url, true);
```

the problem is that if, for example, the variable psid contain some & char, like "test.php?P1=12&P2=232&P3=123" the call pass just part "test.php?P1=12", truncate at the first &.
I have to use this method and not jQuery $.post but i can't figure out how is possible pass variable with & char within.

Thanks in advance

AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is the character used to separate key/value pairs in form encoded data (including in query strings).

You have to escape it as `%26` if you want to send it as data.

[`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) will do that for you.